# Rename collection with pyArango

Tags: python, arangodb, pyarango

I'm trying to rename a ArangoDB collection using [pyArango](http://bioinfo.iric.ca/~daoudat/pyArango/collection.html). This is what I have so far:

```
connection = pyArango.Connection('http://random-address', username='random-username', password='random-password')
test_db = Database(connection, 'test-db')
collection = test_db["new"]
collection.action("PUT", "rename", name="newname")
```

The code fails in line 4:

> {'error': True, 'code': 400, 'errorNum': 1208, 'errorMessage': 'name
>   must be non-empty'}

I'm probably using the `action` method incorrectly but the documentation does not provide any examples. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it like this:

```
def rename_collection(arango_uri, username, password, database, collection, new_name):
    url = '{}/_db/{}/_api/collection/{}/rename'.format(arango_uri, database, collection)
    params = {"name": new_name}
    response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(params), auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

A JSON object `{"name": "newname"}` needs to be passed as request body. The new name can not be passed as URL path parameter. The problem is the implementation of `collection.action()`:

```
def action(self, method, action, **params) :
    "a generic fct for interacting everything that doesn't have an assigned fct"
    fct = getattr(self.connection.session, method.lower())
    r = fct(self.URL + "/" + action, params = params)
    return r.json()
```

The keyword arguments end up as dict called `params`. This object is passed to the request function `fct()` as named parameter `params`. This parameter receives the dict and converts it to URL path parameters, e.g. `?name=newname` which is not supported by the HTTP API of the server.

There is unfortunately no way to pass a payload via `action()`. You can write some custom code however:

```
from pyArango.connection import *
connection = Connection('http://localhost:8529', username='root', password='')

try:
    connection.createDatabase('test-db')
except CreationError:
    pass
test_db = Database(connection, 'test-db')

try:
    test_db.createCollection(name='new')
except CreationError:
    pass
collection = test_db['new']

r = connection.session.put(collection.URL + '/rename', data='{"name":"newname"}')
print(r.text)
collection = test_db['newname']
```

You can also use a dict for the payload and transform it to JSON if you want:

```
import json
...put(..., data=json.dumps({"name": "newname"}))
```